# What is the conjugate of $i$ (iota)?

Tags: complex-numbers

After solving a bunch of stuff I got to $\ arg(1/-i)$.
What does this mean geometrically, and moreover, will the conjugate of $i$ be $-i$ or just $i$ itself?

Comment: Definition of conjugate: every complex number $z$ can be written in the form $z=a+ib$, where $a,b$ are real. Then $a-ib$ is the conjugate of $z$. In this case, $a=0,b=1$ for $z=i$. Change the sign of $b$ , and you have $-1$. But I am somewhat surprised, because somehow I think the question is more difficult than I make it out to be. The conjugate also corresponds to reflection along the x-axis. Furthermore, $\overline{z} = \frac{|z|}z$, so the conjugate of $i$ is in fact $\frac 1i = -i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically the conjugation of a complex number corresponds to taking its reflection with respect to the $x$-axis. In the case of $i$, you can think of it as the point $(0,1)$ in the plane. Therefore its reflection with respect to the $x$-axis is the point $(0,-1)$ which is $-i$.

The result you obtained is consistent with this since $1/-i=i/i^2=i$.